# Surrogate pair that does not start in D800–DBFF

Tags: java, unicode, docx

I am parsing a docx file (in Java) and it has a 32-bit Chinese character using the values F0, A0, 9C, 8E. But the unicode spec says that the high surrogate value needs to be in the range D800–DBFF.

What/why/how is the first value allowed to be F0A0?

And Java converts this to E2, 96, AB, E2, 96, AB somehow. Any idea what's going on with that?

**Update:**

Ok, this is in the document.xml (in the docx file) which is set to UTF-8. I'm reading it using dom4j. So the issue could well be how it is reading it into a String or writing it back out.

How should this be represented in the String object?

Comment: Hmm. U+F0A0 is reported as invalid, but has a Chinese glyph: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f0a0/index.htm U+9C8E is "Unicode Han Character 'king crab' " - are either of those the character you're looking for?

Comment: @JonSkeet the entire sequence is shown as a single character in the Word file, not two. I think it's a UTF-8 4 byte sequence (see my edit).

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like this is the surrogate pair d841, df0e which ends up as [U+2070e](http://unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=2070E) - does that look like the character in the doc?

Comment: (Are F0 A0 9C 8E the *bytes* in the original doc?)

Comment: @JonSkeet - yes, that is the byte sequence in the raw xml file. thank you for helping!

Comment: Right. At that point, could you provide a [mcve] that reads the file with dom4j? The sample XML can just be a single element with the value in...

Comment: XML is usually UTF-8 (look at the encoding specified in the header), and [F0, A0, 9C, 8E] is the encoding for "". [E2, 96, AB,   E2, 96, AB] is the encoding for two white squares "▫▫", which probably means that one of the libraries you're using doesn't support Unicode characters above U+FFFF.

Comment: In UTF-8, `F0 A0 9C 8E` is the Unicode character `""` (U+2070E). In UTF-16LE, those same bytes would be the Unicode character sequence `"ꃰ躜"` (U+A0F0 U+8E9C). What is the *actual* `Encoding` specified in the XML prolog? Or, if there is no `Encoding` specified, does the XML start with a UTF BOM?

Comment: @JonSkeet - building the simple example I found the issue. At one point it was copying to a StringBuffer and not handling double char characters correctly. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @DavidThielen: The lesson here is that building the small sample code is a really good way of either coming up with a good question, or solving it yourself :)

Comment: @JonSkeet - oh yeah. Took me back to the days of DBCS characters which supposedly unicode had eliminated.